# Need help rendering .prepend text in SharePoint

Tags: jquery, xslt

Folks,

I am trying to use the jQuery .prepend method to display some text on the top of  a web part page (underneath the main header). Unfortunately, the text is not rendering across the hole page, it stops at the first column mark. This occurs even though I have tried to prepend it to the mainData table. I have tried prepend it to the header which appears to go all the way across the page to now avail. I believe it must be due to the template but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the way it renders.
[image: Page]

Here is the code.
[image: Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('tbody#mainTableBody').prepend('<tr><td colspan="2"><div id="whoproxy">' + whoproxy + '</td></tr>');
```